# Generating concrete classes in OpenApi spec for Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, swagger, openapi

The problem I’m having is to do with generating the swagger for the api. When you have an object where a property returns an interface, the swagger generator only serializes the interface. What we need to do is use the “OneOf" directive in swagger so we can specify which concrete classes are supported for this property. See the example below.

The swashbuckler nugget package supports the OneOf generation, but swashbuckler does not work by itself with azure functions.
There is a community created nugget package that gets swashbuckler to work with azure functions, but that has been discontinued and also doesn’t support OneOf.
Microsoft have created a replacement for those packages, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi, but that does not support OneOf.

```
    public class Person
    {
        [FunctionName("Person")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {

            return new OkResult();
        }
    }

    public class PersonResponse
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public IPersonData Data { get; set; }

    }

    public interface IPersonData
    {
        string PersonType { get; set; }
    }

    public class PerosnA : IPersonData
    {
        public string PersonType { get; set; }
        public bool AnProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonB : IPersonData
    {
        public string PersonType { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the swagger it should generate. You can paste it into https://editor.swagger.io to validate:

```
{
   "openapi":"3.0.1",
   "info":{
      "title":"API",
      "version":"0.1"
   },
   "servers":[
      {
         "url":"https":
      }
   ],
   "paths":{
      "/Person":{
         "get":{
            "tags":[
               "Person"
            ],
            "summary":"Get a Person record",
            "description":"Get a Person record",
            "operationId":"GetPerson",
            "responses":{
               "200":{
                  "description":"successful operation",
                  "content":{
                     "application/json":{
                        "schema":{
                           "$ref":"#/components/schemas/PersonResponse"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "components":{
      "schemas":{
         "PersonResponse":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
               "Id":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "Data":{
                  "type":"array",
                  "items":{
                     "oneOf":[
                        {
                           "$ref":"#/components/schemas/PersonDataA"
                        },
                        {
                           "$ref":"#/components/schemas/PersonDataB"
                        }
                     ],
                     "discriminator":{
                        "propertyName":"PersonType"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "PersonDataA":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
               "PersonType":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "AnProperty":{
                  "type":"boolean"
               }
            }
         },
         "PersonDataB":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
               "PersonType":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "Something":{
                  "type":"string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```